# Change text inside the comment box

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

When I click on the comment button which exists below the answer, I see some text like

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

It would be better if it was like,

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks". If you want to say thanks to the answerer please do in the form of upvoting or accepting.

Because new users(op) still adding thank you comment. Most of them don't know what to do next. If the text inside the comment box is like above. Then they think about  "what is accepting?". Maybe the link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer would be better.

And also this would avoid reply comment by answerer "Accept an answer which you likes the most" or "Accept if this works." for the op's comment "Thanks, this is what I'm looking for."

Comment: The "or accepting" clause might lead to some confusion.  The OP may think he can accept multiple answers as a way to say thanks to each of the authors.  Perhaps it should be reworded to make it clear you should only accept the one answer that was most helpful (not sure how to do this though).

Comment: Now you see why new users thank answers in comments - this stuff would go waaaaay over any new user's head. It doesn't help that users *cannot upvote* until they have at least 15 rep. How often do you get comments saying something like "thanks, I don't have enough rep to upvote"? I last received one just [earlier this week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076340/selection-inheritance-selection-moz-selection/29076509#comment46386517_29076509).

Comment: Also, that would make the text nearly twice as big, worse if any of the neccessary elaboration is added. Considering that *nobody reads anything*...

Comment: What? I thought I heard something. Never mind. Probably just the wind.

Comment: like `Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks". If you want to say thanks to the answerer please do in the form of upvoting (min 15 rep required) or accepting (but one for a question).`

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out already, people don't tend to read this sort of text unless they are completely stopped from doing what they wanted - and in many cases not even then.

I feel this will add unnecessary verbiage to something that's already borderline.